# Change handler for semantic-ui-react checkbox does not work : React+Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, semantic-ui-react

I am having two semantic-ui-react checkboxes. When I am trying to attach   change handlers, I get a value of 'undefined' when I console log .

Want to fetch both of the checkbox values.

Link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vo8v4996k

Where am I going wrong?

Help would be appreciated

```
import React from "react";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Checkbox } from "semantic-ui-react";

import Form from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/collections/Form';

export default class App extends React.Component<{},{}> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cb1: true,
      cb2: true
    };
  }

  checkboxChangeHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    console.log(name); // It is giving undefined here
    if (name === "cb1") {
      this.setState({ cb1: !this.state.cb1 });
    }
    if (name === "cb2") {
      this.setState({ cb2: !this.state.cb2 });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
       <Form>
        <Checkbox
          label={"CB1"}
          name="cb1"
          checked={this.state.cb1}
          onChange={this.checkboxChangeHandler}
        />
        <Checkbox
          label={"CB2"}
          checked={this.state.cb2}
          name="cb2"
          onChange={this.checkboxChangeHandler}
        />
       </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by using second param in callback, it contains all required information.

```
checkboxChangeHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
    this.setState({ [data.name]: value });
};
```

Working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/31oq13p3o1

Answer (score 4):

The way you have hooked up your event and the way you are accessing it is incorrect.

To fix it change:

```
onChange = {this.checkboxChangeHandler}
```

and

```
let name = event.target.name;
```

to:

```
onChange = {e => this.checkboxChangeHandler(e)}
```

and

```
const name = event.target.checked;
```

(Note that I've made "name" a const as you don't need to reassign its value in the function where you are using it)

Also note that you need to change the signature of your change handler from React.FormEvent to React.ChangeEvent i.e.

```
checkboxChangeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
```

You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8x88qkmv58).

Comment: It is still giving "undefined" !

Comment: Updated my answer again! Should be working now, see the sandbox example I forked from yours.

Comment: Thank you @Ben Smith! I finally got it working by using the second param inside callback. Have posted my answer